# Keyboard shortcut to select text *in a browser (Chrome)* till the end (or beginning) of a line

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

Looking for a keyboard shortcut to select text *in a browser (Chrome)* till the end (or beginning) of a line.

According to [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201236v) the keyboard shortcut

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>RIGHTARROW</kbd> is meant to

> Select the text between the insertion point and the end of the current
>   line.

This works well in MS Word and text editors, but fails in web browsers. I am aware of the Emacs shortcut `CMD`-`E` ([see this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/342767/318103)) - but this behaves differently: it will select the text till the next "line break character", not till the end of a visible line. I.e., if there is an "automatic" line break in the browser which is not because of a corresponding line break in the HTML source code, the Emacs-like command will select the whole block, typically until the end of the current paragraph, not only the text till the "visible line break".

In contrast, in-text editors or MS Word, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>RIGHTARROW</kbd> will select text only till the end of the "visible line". It also works in text boxes in the browser (like the one you use to create a question or answer here), but unfortunately not in "normal web pages".

Comment: It does state "The behavior of these shortcuts may vary with the app you're using." in the section the shortcut is shown. Also, in general, the shortcuts shown in the **Document shortcuts** section of [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/HT201236) are meant for editable fields in apps that support the creation and editing of text documents, not HTML documents displayed in Browsers.

Comment: Thx. I still wonder whether there is a similar shortcut which would work in Chrome.

Comment: There isn't, as that is not how Browsers work for the rendered HTML code.

Comment: You can select a _word_ and then hold **shift-option** while pressing **right arrow** to continue selecting additional _words_.

Comment: Thx, I know this, but it is rather lengthy for long lines :-), still +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can. The shortcut that works is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>.

In other words, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> instead of <kbd>CMD</kbd>, and it works exactly as expected.

But this drives me CRAZY, because I don't want to use different shortcuts across different apps on my mac... I'm desperately looking for a solution to make the original CMD+SHIFT+ARROW work on Chrome as well, if you have any idea how, please help!

Comment: Shift+Ctrl+←/→ makes no difference on my computer (Chrome v106.0 / Monterey v12.6) when trying to expand the selected text on a webpage. The only thing that helps, after selecting a few characters in the targeted text on a webpage with a mouse, is  Shift+Alt++←/→ which expands selected text only one word at a time. This shortcut is also mentioned in one of the comments to the question.

Comment: This is weird... I have the same chrome and Mac OS version. Do you have the expected behavior of `⌘` + `⇧` + `←/→` on TextEdit? The `⇧⌥` word selection has always worked but its not what we want : (

Comment: Doesn't work on my Mac (12.6/Monterey) either... in my case, this shortcut is not doing anything. Sure, you are selecting web text? Not the address line or so...

Comment: I would assume we have different keyboards, not being in the same part of the globe. Have you tried other *unexpected* combination of keys along with arrows to see if one of them matches the behavior? It's how I found `⌃⇧←/→` worked for my keyboard, only on webkit browsers and electron apps. Try alt control, command alt, command alt control, IDK, anything you can think of. If you find one that works, then you can solve the issue like I did with a third party software.